# python mock find where method was called

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest

I am working on a project that has some pytests, in one of the tests I have the following line:

```
mocked_class = Mock()    
assert mocked_class.send.call_count == 1
```

Now I can not find the place in code where someone is calling the `send` method.
I tried to add

```
mocked_class.send=my_method
```

and added prints on that or put breakpoint, but it did not work.

So it seems that I am missing something

The tests are working on python 3.8
with

```
import pytest
from mock import Mock
```

How can I find who calls this method?
Any other help of debuging this

Answer (score 0):

`send` might not exist in your code since its part of a `Mock` instance and you can call arbitrary methods from a `Mock` instance:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

def test_1():
    mocked_class = Mock()
    mocked_class.wasda()
    assert mocked_class.wasda.call_count == 1

test_1()
```

There are plenty of examples in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock

Your code should also raise an "AssertionError" since there are no calls to `send` before the assertions statement.